# :first / :first-child doesn't seem to work with Selenium 2

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors

While migrating from Selenium 1 to Selenium 2 I am running into a problem.

I have the structural equivalent of the following:

```html
<ul id="documentType">
    <li><a href="http://somelink.com">first</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://someotherlink.com">second</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://someotherlink.com">third</a></li>
</ul>
```

Previously I would in Selenium 1 use the following css selector to find the first anchor link:

```
#documentType li:first-child a
```

This would work great, however, when I switch to selenium 2 and try and use the equivalent I get element not found.  The following does work but is less precise then I would like.

```
#documentType li a
```

I have tried but could not get to work the following:

```
#documentType li:first a
```

For greater detail I'm using HtmlUnitDriver with the following code:

```java
driver.findElementByCssSelector("#documentType li a");
```

Any help on getting the equivalent of the original selector working I would greatly appreciate it!

I be confused :)

EDIT: Phill Sacre brought up a good point on the fact I'm directly using HtmlUnitDriver which could be the source of the problem since it's a pure java implementation.  I do this specifically for the ability to deal with a nasty Ajax problem of how to know when Ajax is done running.  You can do this with the following code:

```
protected void waitForAjaxToComplete() {
  long result = jQueryActive();
  while (result != 0) {
    result = (Long) driver.executeScript("return jQuery.active;");
  }
}
```

This is obviously advantageous over using the technique of waiting for an element to appear which can be very inaccurate. I wish WebDriver would expose the executeScript method which would resolve this problem.

Further I noted that by default HtmlUnitDriver does use a java based implementation to parse the css selector supplied and I'm guessing this is the source of the problem.  The parser is com.steadystate.css.parser.SACParserCSS21.SACParserCSS21 which may not properly take into account the :first and :first-child qualifiers.

What seems to make this ok is that the behavior of HtmlUnitDriver seems to return the first element by default.  It's sister method findElementsByCssSelector seems to return an ordered list.

As a result while this appears to be a bug I may have answered my own question by learning how HtmlUnitDriver operates.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser were you doing your Selenium 1 testing on? Looking in the Selenium documentation, the [HtmlUnit driver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#htmlunit-driver) is a pure-Java solution (i.e. it doesn't run in a browser, obviously).

Now I think there are some differences in selectors between browsers, so if you were using the Firefox browser before it may be worth using the FirefoxDriver to run your Selenium 2 tests?

Comment: I am using the firefox driver before the tests.  I think that our goal is to be able to change which driver we are using under the covers of the HtmlUnitDriver.  I could try switching to FirefoxDriver directly but does that mean that there is a bug with the HtmlUnitDriver?

Comment: Also I think we would prefer to keep the tests headless and if I understand the FirefoxDriver we would have to run Firefox for it to work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about using a driver 'under the covers' of the HtmlUnitDriver. If you use the WebDriver interface you should be able to swap in implementations as needed. I would try with the FirefoxDriver directly, however you're doing it.

Comment: The reason I didn't use WebDriver directly is I couldn't figure out how to get it to handle Ajax properly.  With any of the sub drivers I could use the following code snippit to handle ajax updates of pages:   protected void waitForAjaxToComplete() {
    long result = jQueryActive();
    while (result != 0) {
      result = (Long) driver.executeScript("return jQuery.active;");
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Phill's answer- HtmlUnit parser the page differently than FF. I would start the debugging process by running the same test using the FF driver and see if it passes there. If it does pass, then the next step I would do is get the HTML from the HtmlUnit driver (I guess the command would be `driver.getPageHtml()` or something similar). I would compare that html with the html you get when you look at the html through a real browser (FF, chrome,..). Sometimes you see that tags have been put in by the real browser (i.e., by its parser) or by the HtmlUnit browser. You can either correct your selector or use a different driver (or go tell the developers to fix their html because that what usually causes these problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this selector (using Spock/Geb). This has been resolved in the new version of Geb which is 0.9.2 (which has the changes to the HTML unit driver too). Now $('tr:first-child a') works fine with HTMLUnitDriver

Answer (score 0):

I can provide the following CSS Selectors

```
1. css=#documentType > li > a -- First Link
2. css=#documentType > li+li > a -- Second Link
3. css=#documentType > li+li+li > a -- Third Link
```

else, you can try

```
1.css=#documentType > li:nth-child(2) > a -- Second Link
2.css=#documentType > li:nth-child(3) > a -- Third Link
```